# Product table pivot tagtable get all tags in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query and i want the tags.tag into 1 column seperated by ,

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products 
WHERE product.id IN ('13', '14')

product_tag table    
id
product_id 
tag_id

tags table
id
tag
```

desired result:

`product.name , product.description , tags (colulumn with tags seperated by ,)` .....

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pr.name,pr.description,group_concat(tg.tags)
FROM products pr
INNER JOIN product_tag pt on pr.id=pt.product_id 
INNER JOIN tags tg on tg.id=pt.tag_id
WHERE pr.id IN ('13', '14')
group by pr.name,pr.description
```

Try above code.

Hope this help.

Comment: Return empty, did you forget the product_tag column? There are 3 tables, 1 pivot to couple